# Searching a word in a list

Tags: python, arrays, string, function

I am trying to solve the following question from the Kaggle 30 Days of ML course. But the output is coming as an empty list, what have I done wrong?
Thanks in advance.

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    sentence_lst = []
    for sent in doc_list:
        l = sent.split(' ')
        sentence_lst.append(l)
        
    i_lst = []
    for i, sentlist in enumerate(sentence_lst):
        for word in sentlist:
            if str(word) == str(keyword):
                i_lst.append(i)
            break
    return i_lst
                
                
# Check your answer
# q2.check()
word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'],'horse')
```

Comment: Remove the `break` from your loop. Otherwise it only works if the word you look for is the first one in the sentence (or put the `break` in the `if`).

Answer (score 0):

Your program was almost correct. I added a `print()` below `for word in sentlist` and then realise that only the first word was checked in each sentence. Then, you can find out that the `break` is missplaced, it should be in the if statement.

Try this:

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    """
    Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
    Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
    containing the keyword.

    Example:
    doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
    >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
    >>> [0]
    """
    sentence_lst = []
    for sent in doc_list:
        l = sent.split(' ')
        sentence_lst.append(l)
    print(sentence_lst)
    i_lst = []
    for i, sentlist in enumerate(sentence_lst):
        for word in sentlist:
            if str(word) == str(keyword):
                i_lst.append(i)
                break
    return i_lst
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use list comprehension to reduce the size too:

```py
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
    print([idx for idx, sentence in enumerate(doc_list) if keyword.lower() in sentence.lower()])

word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'horse')
>> [0]
word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'something')
>> []
```